does anyone know of a reliable algorithm to find the zeros of a Blaschke product on the upper half plane?
Given a finite Blaschke product, analytic on the upper half plane, defined by $B(z) = \prod_{l=1}^L (z-z_l)/(z-\overline{z_l})$ (the definition used, for example, in Mikayelyan and Hayrapetyan, Armenian journal of mathematics 2020) does anyone know of a reliable algorithm for estimating $z_l$ when $f(z)\in {\cal C}$, $|f(x)|=1$ for $x\in{\cal R}$,  is to be approximated by $B(z)$ with knowledge of $f(z)$ only on the real axis?, i.e. where we assume $f(x_i) \approx B(x_i)$ at samples $x_i\in {\cal R}$ when $L$ is large? This would seem to be a fundamental question for engineering applications, but I can't find an answer searching the web. I've considered a least squares Vandermonde approach (e.g. using the SVD algorithm in the Lapack library), expanding $f(x)$ as a polynomial with complex coefficients, followed by use of the companion matrix to estimate the roots, but this does not enforce the constraints $|f(x)|=1$ nor the requirement that $\Im (z_l)>0$
